# remove header from CSV file when string is found (ms dos command line)

Tags: csv, batch-file, command-line-tool

I need to process the following csv with a dos command line to save it as a bat file.
The file has a resizable header I need to delete, and keep the other lines once a specific string is found 
In this case, I only want to keep the lines after the string "Date" is found.
an example of the file below:

```
CSV:
----

Report,Begin Date,End Date,Currency,Change Currency
Financial Report,2016-03-26 00:00:00.000 -0600,2016-03-27 00:00:00.000 -0600,USD,Change Currency

Method,Deposits,Withdrawals,Reversepayouts,Reversedeposits,Net
PAYPAL,200.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,200.00
VISA2,1650.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1650.00
VISA3,190.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,190.00
DISCOUNT,200.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,200.00
Total:,2240.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2240.00

Date,Affiliate,Username,Account Id,Method,Type,Amount,Transaction Id,Note
2016-03-26 00:36:01.746 -0600,JamesX,ad123,30153,VISA2,Deposit,32.0000,244258410,VISA2
2016-03-26 01:25:53.680 -0600,JamesX,ad123,30153,VISA2,Deposit,32.0000,244263044,VISA2
2016-03-26 02:26:05.776 -0600,ChristineY,Sar,30887,ARESYS,Deposit,200.0000,244267597,PAYPAL
2016-03-26 03:53:28.313 -0600,ChristineY,doo15,35088,VISA2,Deposit,100.0000,244271237,VISA2
2016-03-26 05:01:14.420 -0600,ChristineY,doo15,35088,VISA2,Deposit,320.0000,244273790,VISA2
2016-03-26 08:40:38.593 -0600,JamesX,ad123,30153,VISA2,Deposit,33.0000,244290455,VISA2
2016-03-26 10:08:43.230 -0600,xAZER,veso,36504,VISA3,Deposit,90.0000,244302244,VISA3
```

Comment: The string "Date" is on the first line. Did you just want to remove the first line, or did you only want to keep the lines that start with the date?

Comment: You are right to ask... Only the from the line starting with "DATE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [a regular expression find/replace utility called JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The solution is a basic regex find/replace with a bit of user supplied JScript to handle the logic of which lines to discard.

If you want to discard the "Date,..." header line, then:

```
jrepl "^(Date,)?.*" "($1?i++:i)?$0:false" /jmatch /jbeg "var i=0" /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

If you want to preserve the header line, then only a slight change is needed:

```
jrepl "^(Date,)?.*" "($1?++i:i)?$0:false" /jmatch /jbeg "var i=0" /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

Use `/o -` if you want to overwrite the original file with the result.

Use `call jrepl` if you put the command within a batch script.

It is possible to to solve without user supplied JScript; but that requires the `/m` (multiline) switch, which loads the entire file into memory, so the maximum file size is limited to around 1GB.

Discard the header line:

```
jrepl "[\S\s]*?^Date,.*\n?([\S\s]*)" "$1" /m /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

Preserve the header line:

```
jrepl "[\S\s]*?(^Date,[\S\s]*)" "$1" /m /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

Comment: congrats. Very straight forward solution!

Comment: your expertise could help me again! I have the same issue with this file below, but I also need to insert the date in first column

Comment: @RenaudDUGERT - That sounds like a new question. But if you want to use JREPL.BAT, you should learn regular expressions, as well as rudimentary JScript. Full JREPL.BAT documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`. You ought to try to solve it yourself before you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36240256.csv"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.csv"
SET "reproduce="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED reproduce (
  ECHO(%%a|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"Date," >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "reproduce=y"
 )
 IF DEFINED reproduce ECHO(%%a
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36240256.csv` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Set the `reproduce` flag to *nothing* (so it is undefined)

Read each file-line. If `reproduce` is undefined, use `findstr` to see whether the line `/b` begins with `/L` the literal `/c:` constant-string "Date,", disposing of any output.

If the errorlevel produced from the `findstr` is not >1 (ie. 0) then set `reproduce` to something.

If `reproduce` is set, then regurgitate the line and don't worry further about the slow `findstr` for more blinding *vitesse...*